# How to convert this loops to python 3 from c language?

Tags: c, python-3.x

This is in c language

What is the condition should I put in python 3

```
for (row=0; row<4; row++)
{
    for (col = 4; col > row; col--)
    {
          printf(" ");
    }
    for (col =0; col<=row; row++)
    {
          printf("*");
    }

 }
  printf("\n");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for row in range(4):
    for col in range(4,1,1):
        print(" ",end="")
    for col in range(row+1):
        print("*",end="")
    print("\n")
```

You should read the python manual.

I am exactly translating the code with two knowledge: `range()`,`print()` and for looping.